# Delaying Log4j initialization

Tags: java, logging, log4j

My application is going to have a configuration file that configures its settings.

I want this to be the only configuration file the application uses,

The application will be run from a jar file, which means that log4j will be started as soon as the application is run.

Is there any way to delay initialization of log4j so i can use information from configuration file to configure log4j and then start log4j?

Comment: Log4j doesn't start immediately. It loads it's configuration when it is *first used*. If it initializes itself before you explicitly (re-)initialize it, then it's because you use it before then. Either don't, or just accept that the config is the default until you reconfigure it.

Comment: Please think about whether you really want to put the configuration into your own config file with its own syntax. Log4J is well known and documented - are you sure your documentation will be as good? Why not use a good default and refer users to the Log4J documentation?

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas writes, you (or a library you call) obviously use Log4J. But without a short code example, we can't tell you what's going on (Hint: by removing code to get a short example, you might find the culprit yourself).

According to the [Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) it should even be possible (starting from release 2.4) to change the configuration programmatically after Log4J started.